# FirebaseInstanceIdService does not exist

Tags: java, android, firebase, chat

I'm creating a chat app and according to the tutorial I should create this:
[Tutorial example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNbe2.png)

The problem is that nowadays this function (FirebaseInstanceIdService) no longer exists and therefore I cannot use it.
Would anyone advise me with what code to achieve the same result?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FirebaseInstanceIdService has been depracated and replaced with FirebaseMessagingService

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceIdService

`onTokenRefresh` is now `onNewToken`.

Comment: I removed the MyFirebaseIdService class and put the code from onTokenRefresh () to the FirebaseMessaging class to onNewToken () and it looks like it works

Answer (score 0):

Within the class extending **FirebaseMessagingService**, in which you are already overriding onMessageReceived() method, override the **onNewToken(token: String)** method (this replaces the old **onTokenRefresh()**, so all the logic you had there, must be put here).
With Kotlin,

```
override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
    //the logic here
}

override fun onNewToken(token: String) {
    //all the logic of the old FirebaseInstanceIdService.onTokenRefresh() here
    //usually, to send to the app server the instance ID token
    sendTokenToTheAppServer(token)
}
```